# useNavigate() issue in micro frontend app

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm designing a MFE app called header. Implementation is something like below,

**header.js**

```
const headerApp = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const logoClickHandler = () => {
       navigate('/some-route'); // router v6
  }

  return(
      ...
      <Logo onClick={logoClickHandler} />
  )
}
```

**App.js**

**I want to keep/use it like below**

```
  const App = () = {
      return(
         <div>
             <HeaderApp /> // This component just uses useNavigation or <NavLink to='/some-route' />
         </div
      )
  }
```

Problem is Header app doesn't have its own routing mechanism in it. It is just a separate app and to be more specific standalone component and just provides navigations among different MFE apps using `useNavigate()` OR `<NavLink />` router feature.

Since, I'm using `useNaviage()` OR `<NavLink />`, react is asking me to wrap the component inside `<Routes>` (as shown below) which is unnecessary for my header app.

**React Error**

> useNavigate() may be used only in the context of a `<Router>` component.

don't want to end up like below,

```
 const App = () = {
      return(
         <div>
            <Routes>
               <Route path='/' element={ <HeaderApp /> } />      
            </Routes>       
         </div
      )
  }
```

**NOTE** : Routing is handled in separate app called container. Header only provides links for navigations.

Comment: The `useNavigate` hook and `NavLink` component don't need to be wrapped in a `Routes` component, they only need a routing context (*provided by a router*) higher in the ReactTree provided to them. If these are independent apps then they each need their own routing context, otherwise, you will likely need to use vanilla JS to handle any routing actions.

Comment: @DrewReese any example would just help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React Router uses React Context, which is a way of passing information down through the React tree. Because of this, you only need to make sure you have at least *one* `<Router>` as a parent of whatever component is rendering `<headerApp />` for this to work.

If this is not acceptable to you - you want your application to be used in non-React router contexts, for example - you may want to refactor your header application such that it either provides its own React Router instance or accepts the required methods and attributes through props.

It is not possible to use `<NavLink />` or `useNavigate()` without one of the parents of `<headerApp />` using `Router />`.